# Changing sprite Images in Sprite-Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Is there a way to change the image of a sprite which has already been initialized with another image?

I tried:

> ```
> if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"NameX"]) {
>         SKAction *fadeOut = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.3];
>         SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.3];
>
>        [self.sprite runAction:fadeOut];
>
>        [self runAction:fadeOut completion:^{
>
>              self.sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"NameY"];
>
>              [self.sprite runAction:fadeIn]
>
>             }];
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is. Internally, the `spriteNodeWithImageNamed:` class method just uses the image name you pass it to set the node's texture property. That being said, if at any point you want to arbitrarily change the node's texture, you can just set it directly.

```
[self.sprite setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"someOtherImage"]];
```

There are also some SKActions for doing this, in case you want the node to resize or animate between different textures.

```
[self.sprite runAction:[SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"someOtherImage"] resize:YES]];


[self.sprite runAction:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[tex1,tex2,tex3] timePerFrame:0.5 resize:YES restore:YES]];
```

Comment: i prefer modern dot notation: self.sprite.texture = [SKTexture ...]

Answer (score 2):

You must create texture array such as this:

```
 [SKAction animateWithTextures:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"im1.png"],
                               [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"im2.png"],
                               [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"im3.png"],
                               [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"im4.png"], nil] timePerFrame:0.5 resize:YES restore:YES];
```